# Yet another question about translation... Four words

Tags: sentence-translation, motto, english-to-latin-translation

I am currently studying Latin (3rd year in high school); so I do have a mild understanding of the language. I would like to know whether this translation is correct, makes sense and sounds at least a bit natural. Unfortunately, I can't ask my classroom teacher.

I have come up with this *motto* in English, call it a *title* or *heading* if you'd like:

> All lost things, found.
>
> (All things which had been lost, have now been found)

Going by my somehow limited knowledge of Latin, and consulting the Wiktionary, I crafted this:

> Omnes perditae res, inventus.

Now, I don't know if **inveniēns** should be used here, as an active present participle, or **inventus** as a passive perfect participle.

What are your thoughts on this? Any other approach is warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things about your translation. First, *res* is too literal. "All things" in Latin is merely *omnia*, and thus you can fix the gender of *perditae*.

Speaking of which, *perdo* doesn't mean "lost" as in "I can't find it," but "lost" as in "irrevocably destroyed forever." Cf. Catullus' lines:

> Miser Catulle, desinas ineptire, / et quod vides perisse **perditum** ducas.
>
> Wretched Catullus, quit acting foolish / and consider that which has vanished to be **lost** [i.e. she's never coming back!]

I'd offer *amittere* as a good replacement (think "misplace").

Also, on analogy with phrases like *damnant quod non intellegunt*, I'd suggest using a relative clause for your *amittere*.

I'd offer:

> Omnia quae amissa iam reperta sunt.

In English, *found* is a perfect passive participle, so you would keep it the same in Latin. I chose the word *reperio*, which I think captures the nuance better (with the prefix *re-* and all), but *invenio* could work, too, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would very much prefer to keep the _format/structure_ of the phrase, since it'll be part of a series. Is there any way to write it as `[Former state], [current state].` (i.e. `Then lost, now found.`)? Also, I understand the nuance of _perdo_ and I believe it would be suitable for this (or maybe it doesn't work with _invenio_?). About that passive dilemma; I am not that well acquainted with English grammar in detail, since I'm not a native speaker, and my language only deals with one type of participle. Could you please lend me a hand just a bit further on this?

Comment: I didn't realize you were not a native English speaker. I think you could have figured it out very easily, but since you asked, there's the answer. You can remove the *quae* without losing very much: *omnia amissa/perdita iam reperta/inventa sunt*: All lost things are now found.